# Create a torch::Tensor from C/C++ array without using "from_blob(...)..."

Tags: c++, pytorch, libtorch

Using the C++ libtorch frontend for [`Pytorch`](https://pytorch.org/)

I want to create a  `torch::Tensor` from a C++ `double[]` array.  Comming from a legacy C/C++ API.
I could not find a simple documentation about the subject not in [docs](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/frontend.html) nor in the forums.

Something like:

```
double array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};   // or double *array;
auto tharray = torch::Tensor(array, 5, torch::Device(torch::kCUDA));
```

The only thing I found is to use `torch::from_blob` but then I would have to `clone()` and use `to(device)` if I wanted to use it with CUDA.

```
double array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};. // or double *array;
auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat64);
torch::Tensor tharray = torch::from_blob(array, {5}, options);
```

Is there any cleaner way of doing so?

Comment: Can you use [`TensorOptions`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/c10/core/TensorOptions.h) to set the device at the same time you create your tensor? Something like `auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat64).device(torch::kCUDA, 1)`

Answer (score 13):

You can read more about tensor creation here: https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_creation.html

I don't know of any way to create a tensor from an array without using `from_blob` but you can use `TensorOptions` to control various things about the tensor including its device.

Based on your example you could create your tensor on the GPU as follows:

```
double array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto options = torch::TensorOptions().dtype(torch::kFloat64).device(torch::kCUDA, 1);
torch::Tensor tharray = torch::from_blob(array, {5}, options);
```

Comment: no it doesn't work, it still creates on CPU, a `to.device` is still needed

Comment: Does it? How can you tell if it's on the CPU or GPU?

Comment: Yes it works! you are right @JacKeown I was confused by this issue here https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/12506#issuecomment-429573396

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me anymore... I've raise a question about this at: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/create-tensor-on-cuda-device-in-c/113232

Comment: from_blob with kCUDA in options raise an error for me, 

from_blob()clone().to(torch::kCUDA) works. 

see this: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/15426#issuecomment-451225787

Answer (score 6):

I usually use:

```
torch::Tensor tharray = torch::tensor({1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {torch::kFloat64});
```

Comment: well fine people got happy with your answer but the question is regarding a legacy C/C++ array pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have cleaner way, but I would give you another way to do it.

```
double array[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto tharray = torch::zeros(5,torch::kFloat64) //or use kF64
std::memcpy(tharray.data_ptr(),array,sizeof(double)*tharray.numel())
```

Hope its helpful.

Corrected `KF64` to `kFloat64` because `KF64` does not exist in torch